# what is a header only library

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, software-distribution

I am working on using boost C++ libraries for my next project and the documentation says that it is a header only library.

> Most Boost libraries are header-only: they consist entirely of header
>   files containing templates and inline functions, and require no
>   separately-compiled library binaries or special treatment when
>   linking.

So my question is does it mean I do not need to link the library for these boost libraries and including the header is the only requirement ?

what are header only libraries and how are they different from the standard libraries that require building and linking to the binary ?

Comment: Yes, only header files, no source files. Just include the headers you need and you should be good.

Comment: Headers are source files.  It's just that there is nothing to link to because the compiler inlines everything or handles it for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A header-only library, as the name hints, is only made of headers.
That actually means you don't have to link against binaries, because the whole code of this library is contained in headers, and this code will be compiled when you include them in your project.

This kind of libraries is sometimes the only way, for example when dealing with templates.